# Alguém já implementou o SNS da AWS para GCM e APNS?

Tags: amazon-aws

Estou com uma dúvida: nós conseguimos implementar o envio para um device de cada vez, agora estamos precisando fazer o envio em lote, alguém já implementou o *SNS* da *AWS* para *GCM* e *APNS* em lotes?

Comment: Qual realmente é a sua dúvida, já tentou algo? Você pretende enviar essas notificações via app mobile ou via software utilizando a API da amazon?

Comment: Estou tentando enviar via api da AWS, estamos desenvolvendo em Java, mas so conseguimos enviar um de cada vez e estamos precisando enviar em lote...